# 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, api, android-studio, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I'm using api to get the data and When i press the back button from UserProfileActivity and return to ImageViewerActivty I'am getting this error, I've searched through StackOverflow but couldn't find a solution it'd be great if someone could point me towards the solution.

//UserProfileActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    profileImg=(CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.userImg);
    name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.profileUserName);
    location=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.profileLocation);
    bio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.profileBio);
    total_photos=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.profilePhotos);
    instName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.profileInsta);

    rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.profileRv);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    rv.hasFixedSize();
    rv.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(getIntent().getStringExtra("profileImg"))
            .centerCrop()
            .into(profileImg);

    name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("user"));
    location.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("location"));
    bio.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("bio"));
    instName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("instaName"));
    username=getIntent().getStringExtra("username");

    //RECENT PHOTOS FIRST FETCH
    UnsplashService service= ApiClient.getClient().create(UnsplashService.class);
    Call<List<PhotoModel>> call=service.getUserProfile(username,API_KEY,1,PAGE_LIMIT);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PhotoModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<PhotoModel>> call, Response<List<PhotoModel>> response) {
            List<PhotoModel> photoModelList=response.body();
            adapter = new InfinitePhotoAdapter(UserProfileActivity.this, photoModelList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<PhotoModel>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    infiniteScrollListener = new InfiniteScrollListener(gridLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            updatephotos(username,page);
        }
    };

    rv.addOnScrollListener(infiniteScrollListener);

}
```

//ImageViewer

```
public class ImageViewerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String DIR_NAME ="WallUp Wallpapers";
private static final String LOG_TAG =ImageViewerActivity.class.getSimpleName() ;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE =2 ;
ImageView detailImg;
CircularImageView profileImg;
TextView user,location;
Uri imageUri;
DownloadManager downloadManager;
Button downloadBtn,setBtn;
long downloadReference;
Bitmap bmp;
private String filename="Wallpaper.jpg";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_viewer);

    detailImg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.detailImg);
    profileImg=(CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.profileImg);
    user=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user);
    downloadBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
    setBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setBtn);
    location=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.location);

    //Getting User Details from Intent
    user.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("user"));
    location.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("location"));




    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(getIntent().getStringExtra("Image"))
            .centerCrop()
            .into(detailImg);

    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(getIntent().getStringExtra("profileImage"))
            .centerCrop()
            .into(profileImg);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transition));
        detailImg.setTransitionName("sharedTransition");
    }

    imageUri=Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("Image"));

    downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DownloadData(imageUri);
        }
    });

    setBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            detailImg.buildDrawingCache();
            bmp=detailImg.getDrawingCache();
            settingWallpaper(bmp);
        }
    });


    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
    registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant

            return;
        }
    }

    profileImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(ImageViewerActivity.this,UserProfileActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("username",getIntent().getStringExtra("username"));
            i.putExtra("name",getIntent().getStringExtra("user"));
            i.putExtra("profileImg",getIntent().getStringExtra("profileImage"));
            i.putExtra("bio",getIntent().getStringExtra("bio"));
            i.putExtra("instaName",getIntent().getStringExtra("instaName"));
            i.putExtra("totalPhotos",getIntent().getExtras().getInt("total_photos"));
            i.putExtra("location",getIntent().getStringExtra("location"));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });



}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! do the
                downloadBtn.setEnabled(true);


            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                downloadBtn.setEnabled(false);
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'switch' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

private void settingWallpaper(Bitmap bmp){
    WallpaperManager wallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        wallManager.setBitmap(bmp);
        Toast.makeText(ImageViewerActivity.this, "Wallpaper Set Successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ImageViewerActivity.this, "Setting WallPaper Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private long DownloadData (Uri uri) {


    File direct =
            new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_NAME + "/");


    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdir();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dir created for first time");
    }
    // Create request for android download manager
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    //Setting title of request
    request.setTitle("Wallpaper");

    //Setting description of request
    request.setDescription("Wallup Wallpapers")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
                    File.separator + DIR_NAME + File.separator + filename);

    //Enqueue download and save into referenceId
    downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    return downloadReference;
}

private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //check if the broadcast message is for our enqueued download
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

        if (referenceId ==downloadReference ) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ImageViewerActivity.this,
                    "Image Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
    registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(downloadReceiver);
}
```

}

//This is the Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.sohail.wallupwallpapers, PID: 2837
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.sohail.wallupwallpapers/com.sohail.wallupwallpapers.Activities.UserProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4586)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4609)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap7(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:750)
                  at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.refreshBitmapShader(CircularImageView.java:341)
                  at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:262)
                  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:514)
                  at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.ImageViewTarget.onLoadCleared(ImageViewTarget.java:70)
                  at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.clear(GenericRequest.java:323)
                  at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.clearRequests(RequestTracker.java:94)
                  at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.onDestroy(RequestManager.java:221)
                  at com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onDestroy(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java:64)
                  at com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onDestroy(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java:147)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:2588)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1566)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3244)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:3235)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:265)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:390)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:209)
                  at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7195)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1161)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4573)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4609) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap7(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the third party code you are using.  Please review this bug from their project for help and contribute if it looks like the same problem you're seeing.

https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView/issues/52

They suggest setting a placeholder image will prevent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a placeholder.

For glide

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_error);

Glide.with(context)
     .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
     .load(url).into(holder.imageView);
```

For Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: But now my image view is only loading placeholder not the actual image

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (userImageUrl.matches("(?!file\\b)\\w+?:\\/\\/.*")) {
        // Not a local file 
        // image server url
        LogClass.e("userImageUrl", "Not a local file");
        Glide.with(DrawerActivity.this).load(userImageUrl).into(imgProfile);

    } else {
        // local path 
        LogClass.e("userImageUrl", "local file");
        File file = new File(userImageUrl);
        String filePath = file.getPath();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```